# Having trouble solving equation with Sympy? Ideas?

Tags: python, sympy, solver

I am trying to solve an equation using Sympy. I have generated the relevant equation using a for loop and already have values for r1, r2, r3, and c. I want to use SymPy to solve for r4. However, when I try to use solveset, I am not getting a solution for r4, but rather a

This is my equation and when I try to use solveset:

```py
101.947638 - (c/2)*(exp(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.00273972602739726*r3) + exp(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.476712328767123*r3 - 1.02465753424658*r4) + exp(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.476712328767123*r3 - 0.526027397260274*r4) + exp(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.476712328767123*r3 - 0.0246575342465753*r4) - 100*exp(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.476712328767123*r3 - 1.02465753424658*r4)
```

I get:

```py
ConditionSet(r4, Eq(-1.0625*2.71828182845905**(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.00273972602739726*r3) - 101.0625*2.71828182845905**(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.476712328767123*r3 - 1.02465753424658*r4) - 1.0625*2.71828182845905**(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.476712328767123*r3 - 0.526027397260274*r4) - 1.0625*2.71828182845905**(-0.252054794520548*r1 - 0.252054794520548*r2 - 0.476712328767123*r3 - 0.0246575342465753*r4) + 100.0918, 0), Complexes(S.Reals x S.Reals, False))
```

Can someone help me use SymPy to solve this equation?

Comment: Dont you have 4 unknowns with just 1 equation?

Comment: No I know the values of r1, r2, r3, and c. Just need to solve for r4

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you did something like this:

```
>>> from sympy.abc import x, y
>>> eq = y + 2*x
>>> for x in range(2):
...     print(eq)
y + 2*x
y + 2*x
```

Notice that having a value of `x` in the loop doesn't magically substitute that value into `eq` for you. The `x` definition when `eq` was created was a symbol. When the loop begins, x becomes an in but the definition of `eq` has not changed; that's just how Python works. What you need to do is use a different variable for the values that you want to substitute into the equation, something like this:

```
>>> for xi in range(2):
...     print(eq.subs({x: xi}))
y
y + 2
```

So make sure to substitute in the values for r1, r2, r3 and c before trying to solve the equation.